# С# Вопрос по Chart.Series!

Tags: c#, диаграммы

Возможно ли написать код к примеру:
Если `Chart.Series[0]` существует, то ввести `Chart.Series[1]` и на оборот?
Смысл в том, что нужно уместить два графика на одном `chart`, но из-за конфликта со `series[]`, это сделать невозможно.
Или возможно каким то путём написать код к примеру: `chart.chartAreas[].series[].points.add(x,y)`?

Comment: Ошибка всегда у меня такова:
System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Индекс за пределами диапазона. Индекс должен быть положительным числом, а его размер не должен превышать размер коллекции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... нужно уместить два графика на одном

```
Chart.Series.Clear();

var series1_name = "Series1";
var series2_name = "Series2";

Chart.Series.Add(series1_name);
Chart.Series.Add(series2_name);
Chart.Series[series1_name].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
Chart.Series[series2_name].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
Chart.Series[series1_name].Points.AddXY(x, y1); // Добавили точку для первого графика
Chart.Series[series2_name].Points.AddXY(x, y2); // Добавили точку для второго графика

// И т.д.
```

**UPD.** (после комментария под ответом)

Пусть `button1` обновляет `"Series1"`, а `button2` обновляет `"Series2"`, тогда:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    Chart.Series["Series1"].Points.Clear(); // Очищает коллекцию точек "Series1"

    // Теперь можно заново добавлять точки
    Chart.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(1, 1);

}  

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    Chart.Series["Series2"].Points.Clear(); // Очищает коллекцию точек "Series2"

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Хороший метод, но у меня ещё один вопрос, как мне поступить, если у меня 2 графика находятся на двух кнопках (не по одному щелчку). 
Дело в том, что их надо перед построем чистить Chart.Series.Clear() , но если я это сделаю, то очистится другой график.
Не используя clear(), выдаёт такую ошибку: System.ArgumentException: Элемент диаграммы с именем "Series2" уже существует в "SeriesCollection".

Comment: @ElemStack обновил вопрос.